# I disagree with a duplicate closure by a user holding a gold tag badge

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I think ModularSynth is improperly using the Android badge dupe-hammer to mark [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149193/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-on-a-null-objec?noredirect=1#comment79262979_46149193) as a duplicate of a JNE.

I tried to explain in the comments that actually the problem is deeper and the JNE is only a side-effect, but not the real problem in that question. The question is actually a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android), instead.

I wanted to post a proper answer to the question, because I think it could be very helpful in similar cases, but I cannot as the issue has been erroneously marked as a duplicate.

I was unsuccessful in persuading the user who closed the question to change his mind via comment replies. What are my options?

Comment: Wait, that's funny ^^ ... you know that question is a dupe of another question, yet you want it reopened to _answer_ it? Do you know what the dupe system is for?

Comment: Looks like a dupe to me. The underlying *cause* may be something else, but the OP should *first* read the NPE question and answers, then change their question appropriately to indicate where they're getting a null reference, and ask *why that's null* rather than *why they're getting an exception*.

Comment: There is excessively little point in arguing about this.  Just ask the question yourself, be sure to do a better job of asking it, and post the answer.  Then post a link to it in a comment.

Comment: @HansPassant: _"Then vote this one as a duplicate."_ It's already closed as dupe, which appears to be the whole issue.

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: @Tom if you read my comments on that issue, on one side I wanted to link it to the proper duplicate; on the other hand yes I wanted to reply anyway (it was opened initially) so that everyone would read the proper answer, because I see the same issue is taken wrongly over and over again. I've no idea what is the dupe system, need to look it up

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the suggestion, I thought about it, maybe I will.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right on the correct procedure, but I've no influence on that

Comment: The point is that it's already closed correctly. While the question is "Why am I getting an NPE?" the correct dupe is the NPE one. So the whole "How can I get it closed as a dupe of something else" becomes irrelevant (and, I'd say, misguided).

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, you're definitely correct. I didn't see it like this before I actually opened this issue, as I thought that the real question was another one. But reading again the issue literally, as long as the user keeps that title and that text, yes the question is about NPE, even if the problem is something else

Answer (score 8):

First of all, that person is *not a "moderator"*.
ModularSynth is a normal user with a gold badge in [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), which [allows them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212) to close the question as duplicate.

The other issue:

> *"The issue is actually a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android) instead. I wanted to post a proper answer"*

Please don't answer questions you *know* are duplicates.
Close-vote them as duplicate, instead (Assuming they're still open)

Comment: thanks to clarify ModularSynth not to be a moderator, my bad. About the close-voting, I would have liked to answer, because if marked as duplicate of my suggested duplicate, any reader goes to the duplicate, and there the most voted answer suggests what the issue is already doing (static context in Android, which causes the JNE). So answering would make a reader to be conscious instead of the real problem, imho.

Comment: @Alessio: I usually close as dupe, and comment in cases like that, pointing them to the right answer.

Comment: Thanks I'll try your suggestion as well

Comment: @Alessio if you found better duplicate than pinging gold badger that closed the question with comment suggesting another duplicate would be much better approach than answering with duplicate. Gold badgers can edit list of duplicates to add new one. (Note that in this particular question standard NPE/NRE closure is probably fine, OP needs to come up with much better MCVE for such questions to stand on its own or even deserve unique duplicate).